# Pattern validation in Javascript with a dot in number

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, pattern-matching

Why the following pattern check returns true?

```
var pattern = /^[0-9]+(\.([0-9]{1,3})?)?$/;
var val = "10.";
var check = pattern.test(val); // returns true
```

Comment: Because `?` match between 0 or 1 of the preceding token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why the following pattern check returns true?

Because `val.toString()` is `10`

and as per [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-regexp.prototype.test) arguments to `test` is converted to string first.

> Let pattern be ToString(Get(R, "source")).

Also, you have an extra `?` after `([0-9]{1,3})?`, remove that as well and try

```
var pattern = /^[0-9]+(\.([0-9]{1,3}))?$/;
var val = "10.";
pattern.test(val); // returns false
```

**Demo**

```js
var pattern = /^[0-9]+(\.([0-9]{1,3}))?$/;
var val = "10.";
console.log(pattern.test(val));
```